# vimscript: how to repeat a string N times?

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

I know `.` operator concatenate strings.

But how to repeat a string N times, similar to `"abc" * 3` in python?

Comment: FYI, [`:help function-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#function-list) is a very useful page when VimScripting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To repeat a string you want to use the (appropriately named) function `repeat()`

The doc is here [`:h repeat()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#repeat%28%29)

And you can use it like that:

```
let foo = repeat("abc", 3)
```